# How to split a column into three columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of a soccer league:

```
df.Game.head()

0    Man. City @Cardiff City
1     Southampton @Liverpool
2        Tottenham @Brighton
3          Chelsea @West Ham
4         Wolves @Man United
```

The symbol '@' before the team name indicates home team. I want to split the column into three separate columns:

1. team_1: Team one
2. team_2: Team two
3. home: The home team (which has @ before the name and always comes at the second)

I have tried the following code:

```
df[['team_1', 'team_2']] = df.Game.str.split(' @', expand = True)

df['home'] = df.Game.str.split(' @', expand = True)[1]
```

Is there any better way to do that? Maybe a single-line code? Thank you!

Comment: Does the home team always come second? Or are there rows where, for example, you have this string `@Chelsea West Ham`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to `split` twice

```
df[['team_1', 'team_2']] = df.Game.str.split(' @', expand = True)
df['home'] = df['team 2']
```

Comment: Hi @Ben. You are right. Even I really don't need to split into three. I can split into two -- 'away team' and 'home team' with the first line only. Thanks!